# What should the histogram of an ideal image for training convolutional network look like?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, image-processing

I'm trying to use convolutional networks for classifying images of . In the training set, I noticed large variation in illumination and light intensity. In order to fix this, I'm considering Contrast-limited adaptive histogram equalization ([CLAHE](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html)), which I was planning to use as a black box.
Two parameters of CLAHE are grid size and clip limit.

Grid size defines how the size of tiles the image is divide into and histogram equalization is applied on these sub-images.
In case of clip limit, the part of histogram that exceeds this limit is redistributed. 
I can change the shape of histogram by changing the above arguments, but I'm confused about which parameters to choose for the image transformation with CLAHE.

What I'd like to know is, what should the histogram of ideal images for training deep learning models look like?